# jquery: can't append on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Had same problem a couple of days ago. This time wrote the code remembering where i went wrong last time. Not working again... Answering one of questions in advance. Code inside {{}} is shopify data from settings.

No related errors in console.

What i'm trying to do is to set an icon from shopify theme settings.

Here is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $soicon1 = '{{settings.soc1_brand}}';

  if ($soicon1 == 'facebook') 
  { $(".soctransition1").append("<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>"); }
  else if ($soicon1 == 'twitter') 
  { $(".soctransition1").append("<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>"); }
    else if ($soicon1 == 'youtube') 
  { $(".soctransition1").append("<i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>"); }
      else if ($soicon1 == 'instagram') 
  { $(".soctransition1").append("<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>"); }
       else if ($soicon1 == 'pinterest') 
  { $(".soctransition1").append("<i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>" ); }
});
```

Comment: so how is it rendered out? you also have nested double quotes!

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` in the console because of the unescaped quotation marks. That's a related error...

Comment: Basically, nothing is there. No code appended. Could that be because of double quotes? I'm new to jQ

Comment: The syntax error will keep the entire script block from being parsed. The code won't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var soicon1 = '{{settings.soc1_brand}}';
    if (soicon1 === 'facebook') 
      { $(".soctransition1").append("<i class='fa fa-facebook'></i>"); }
      else if (soicon1 === 'twitter') 
      { $(".soctransition1").append("<i class='fa fa-twitter'></i>"); }
        else if (soicon1 === 'youtube') 
      { $(".soctransition1").append("<i class='fa fa-youtube'></i>"); }
          else if (soicon1 === 'instagram') 
      { $(".soctransition1").append("<i class='fa fa-instagram'></i>"); }
           else if (soicon1 === 'pinterest') 
      { $(".soctransition1").append("<i class='fa fa-pinterest'></i>" ); }
});
```

What I changed:

- removed the $ from the variable `soicon1`
- changed `==` to `===`
- resolved clashes with quotes in instances like `"<i class='fa fa-instagram'></i>"`

Comment: Then there must be an issue with the contents of `{{settings.soc1_brand}}`, for when I substitute it with a hard-coded `facebook`, it works.

Comment: Or perhaps it actually works, but the result is not obvious because the `<i` tags appended are visually empty (if their classes are not specified in the CSS).

Comment: nope. there is no icon tag in source. and shopify code is fine too. Just tried appending <style> on that condition into header. It appended tags, but for some reason no styles. Though something could override them. So, it looks like something is up with the code

Comment: From my experience, dynamically appended/created elements do not appear in the 'traditional' source code. If you're using Google Chrome, right click and select 'Inspect Element'. You will find the `<i` there.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for the `{{settings.soc1_brand}}` variable?

Comment: it's a select tag in shopify settings that has options listed in the script. This script appends style tag to head. Not these icons into div though...

Comment: Can you provide the results of `alert(soicon1);` (add this code after `var soicon1 = '{{settings.soc1_brand}}';`? Also, your styles are predefined right?

Comment: Nothing shows up. Yes styles are predefined. (Could you plz explain logic behind  alert(soicon1);, if it's not a problem )

Comment: The alert is supposed to display the variable specified in a popup that requires the user to click 'OK'. It is a Javascript function. I asked you to implement it so that you could give us a sample of the variable 'soicon1' that is fed into your code. Many factors may be affecting your case, so it would help us help you if you could find a way to give us a sample of the contents of that variable.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer? You're most welcome!

Comment: It's not a java script solution, but it works. That's what matters in the end. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, found a very easy solution.
Instead of appending, i've just put a shopify settings string into icon code.

```
<i class="fa fa-{{settings.soc4_brand}}"></i>
```